# CSRF error occurred in angular2 but all good in Postman (SOAP XML Ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, angular, soap

The SOAP XML Ajax call in Postman:

Request:

```
    Method: Post
    Url: https://domain.com/path
    Content-Type: text/xml
    Body:
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://domain.com/">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            body message
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
     data returned
    </S:Body>
```

And here is the code in Angular2:

```
    //ServiceData as provider 

    import ****; //abbreviation

    export class ServiceData { 
      private url = Setting.API_BASE_DATA;
      private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=utf-8',
                                     'Accept': 'text/xml'});

      constructor(
        private http: Http,
      ) { }
      getStatus(customerNumber: number): Observable<any> {

        let data = `<soapenv:Envelope ...>......abbreviation......
                    </soapenv:Envelope>`; // the data are the same as the previous one.

        return this.http.post(`${this.url}`, data, {headers: this.headers})
                   .map(response => {return response;})
                   .catch(err => {return Observable.throw(err);});
      }
    }

    // Component

    constructor(
       private serviceData: ServiceData,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void{
        this.serviceData.getStatus(384914)
            .subscribe( response => console.log(response),
                        err => console.log(err) );
    }
```

After deployment, the error occurred:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://billingws.utilibill.com.au/tiabwsv2/UtbCustomer?wsdl. Origin domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

This error also happened while using native javascript Ajax, both happened in my local development environment and online server environment.

I guess there must be something wrong in my code.

Is there any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) headers not allowing you to request that domain.

Option1 if you control the domain in question then you can add CORS headers to allow the call. I can see that server uses apache so you can set in the .htaccess

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Option2 if you don't control the domain you will need to use a reverse proxy to so you can make ajax calls to that domain via your own domain.

Comment: Yeah I found that I have to build a middle layer to get the data, thanks bro.